# Does it exsit a presentation mode, with next slide and counter for a pdf?

Tags: pdf

If you do your slides with libreoffice, when you see the diaporama with a double screen option, people see your slides on the screen  where there are projected, and you see the current slide, the next one and a time counter on your laptop.

Is there a way to do the same thing with a pdf viewver ? I usually do my presentation with latex and beamer and such a feature of libreoffice is interesting.

Comment: I confirm the duplicate. Thus see pdfpc.